# Can not install Nginx (error in installing)

Tags: software-installation, nginx

I'm not so smart and pretty nub, so, I've got an error while installing nginx:

> Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Can you help me, please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The picture of the text of your output is hard to read.  Please copy the text from your screen and past it into your question.  Have the text in your question instead of the picture of the text would also make it easier for us to copy and paste from it to search for other discussions with the same issue that may have good resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed apache2 first stop it. Then try to install

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe something your port 80 has taken by some other service . In your current status you should disable the apache2 service rather than stop .

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

and if you think your Nginx installed correctly please restart your Nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart Nginx
```

then check the Nginx status

```
sudo service nginx status
```